# how to bulk add calendar events with powerapps

Tags: calendar, office365, powerapps

i'm messing about with powerapps and attempting to build a small app that adds all my exams into my school's calendar as this will save me (and other students) a lot of time.

at the moment i have already managed to get all the required data from the excel file that contains all exams with their dates, locations, times and much more irrelevant information. this data is filtered to only include the exams for me (and technically all other engineering students if i make it public)
i've stored it in a collection and have no problem using it.
the issue is the outlook/office365 connector as im not shure it can do what i'd like it to do.

```
Office365.V2CalendarPostItem(calendarSelect.Selected,test.'Cursus Omschrijving',test.'Datum/Date',test.Tot,{Location:test.'Locatie/Location'})
```

i've put up a calendar selection dropdown thing as i dont know if all calendars are the same so you can select the right one. `calendarSelect.Selected` is the result of that. `test.'Cursus Omschrijving'` is the title of the exam. the date bit is, well, the date and start time, and `test.Tot`is the end time.
the issue is `Office365.V2CalendarPostItem` expects only one item at a time really. powerapps complains about it recieving a table and not text or a date as it expects.
Do any of you know if it is even possible to do what im planning(bulk adding calendar items) or is powerapps not capable of this and i need to switch over to a more powerful language?